# Can I write a paper on software that I published a year ago?

Tags: publications, code, publishability, software-papers

I am a bachelor-level (software engineering) student. I made [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition) more than a year ago, where I use machine learning and deep learning to identify movements in accelerometer signals.

As of now, the GitHub repository has a thousand stars. There is already research being made derived from my work. As a practical example, [here](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/HAR-stacked-residual-bidir-LSTMs) I collaborated with someone to write a paper.

I wonder: Should I write and publish a paper on the first project, even though it's a year old? What are my options, if any?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to elaborate what would would constitute the novelty of your paper? The software itself, the employed algorithms, or something else?

Comment: I don't understand the title.

Comment: At the end of my graduate career, my _undergraduate_ advisor finally got around to publishing the work I helped do as an undergraduate—six years earlier! So being a year old isn't a problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can publish a paper, if

- you have new ideas in your software that you developed yourself.
- the ideas have not been published by you before.

If other people who have used your software also documented your ideas, cite them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer provided here, but I would also attempt to seek either (preferably) Academic or Industrial advice (companies have their own R&D departments and publish their own papers).

A Professor can give you hands on advice to approach publishing the paper in a specific manner to make your ideas stand out and justify their importance and relevance.

Congrats btw.